# How to check if there is escape character (`) is present in String for Linux Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I was wondering how to check if the string has the escape [`] character in Linux.

```
str="abc|`abc`"
if [[ $str == *[`]* ]]
then
    echo "Escape character is present"
fi
```

I am getting error while using this.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use:

```sh
str='abc|`abc`'

[[ $str == *'`'* ]] && echo 'Escape character is present' || echo 'no'

Escape character is present
```

Make sure to use single quotes around `` ` `` to disallow shell expansion.

PS: You can also use escaping like:

```
[[ $str == *\`* ]]
```

Comment: Will let you know